# Linux Bashrc auto-tabbing not working as subuser

Tags: linux, bash, tabbing

I'm stuck with `.bashrc` at the moment. I have ~/.bashrc for root which works wonderfully. It highlights my `ls` and auto-completes directories with `tab`.

I made a new user named `jesse` and his home directory is under `home/jesse`. When I created him I did not do the "auto create directory", rather I did it manually after creating the user.

With or without a `bashrc` file there is no effect with colors/tabs in the user `jesse`. I am only guessing it had to do with the user creation not auto-creating the home directory for him. I don't understand why my tabs would be broken.

Does anyone know what I've done wrong? Should I adjust the global bash file? If so, what would cause this tab problem?

```
 ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.

# Note: PS1 and umask are already set in /etc/profile. You should not
# need this unless you want different defaults for root.
# PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\h:\w\$ '
# umask 022

export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things could be causing this. Check to see that the jesse account is in fact using bash as the log-in shell, and not sh. Check that `.bashrc` is correctly named and has the right file permissions and ownership. Check that jesse's home directory has the right file permissions. Also have a look in the root user's home directory for any other bash configuration files that could affect bash completion.

Comment: Check that the account uses bash *by looking in /etc/passwd or running chsh*.

Comment: Yes, thank you! It was using bin/sh not bin/bash. $ chsh fixed it for me. I also added .profile to my user folder!